# Make links somewhat more visible in negative-score posts

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, score

Right now the grayed-out style of negative-score posts also results in links being shown just like regular text.

[image]

This is especially annoying in case of well-hidden spam since it's easy to overlook (which in turn might result in a declined spam flag even though it was actually valid).

So I'd like at least *some* styling for links in this case. At least for moderators.

Comment: You have any -3 posts to take a screenshot from :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485617/make-uicollectionview-zoomable/13485639#13485639 or just add `.downvoted-answer` to some answer's div using e.g. firebug.

Comment: Evidently they do have a special rule for `.downvoted-answer .post-text a`, and believe it or not, the rule makes the opacity for the link `0.7` and the text gray. In other words, *there is a rule specifically designed to make that link harder to see*. (?)

Comment: Yeah, and at least for moderators (possibly also 10k+ users, but maybe even all users who can flag things) - or simply in all flag queues no matter which one - this is a horrible feature.